# Spring Web app with setup wizard for database configuration

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I want my Spring 3.1 + JPA + Hibernate web app to have a set up wizard for database properties on first run. I use JPA annotations for my model layer and all the configurations are in xml format i.e (dispatcher-servlet.xml, application-context.xml ). I have a pre-existing mysql.jdbc.properties files that is read to the application context during deployment. I want to allow the user to enter the database properties in a web browser(database name,url,username,password) then the app generates the database tables. How do I do that?

I need to specify that the current setup is as follows
My configuration for JPA & Hibernate is as follows:I have a pre-existing mysql.jdbc.properties files that is read to the application context during deployment using ***org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResosurceBundleMessageSource*** bean class.
My data configuration beans look like these:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverM anagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerE ntityManagerFactoryBean"
p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
packagesToScan-ref="jpaPackages"
p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateVendor"
p:jpaPropertyMap-ref="jpaPropertyMap" />

<util:list id="jpaPackages">
<value>org.kemri.wellcome.dhisreport.api.model</value>
<value>org.hisp.dhis.dxf2.importsummary</value>
</util:list>

<bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
p:showSql="false"/>
```

I want to allow the user to enter the database properties in a web browser(database name,url,username,password) then the app generates the database tables on web app first-run

Comment: Good question, I have never seen JPA + Hibernate dynamically configured, I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: I hope so.This would greatly help in extending some features

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `Configuration` at runtime:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
```

The `Configuration` class many methods to add your entities. For example you can do:

```
cfg.addPackage("com.foo.bar");
```

You set your properties using `Configuration.setProperty()`. I suggest you read the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

With this configuration Hibernate can generate DDL by using `SchemaExport`. First create one:

```
SchemaExport se = SchemaExport(cfg);
```

Then run the script using `create`:

```
se.create(true, true);
```

**EDIT**: After some research i found this can be done within Spring, so you don't have to create and build a session again. See this article: http://hillert.blogspot.com/2010/05/using-hibernates-schemaexport-feature.html